# USB reader is not working

Tags: usb

My USB ports are no longer working properly. I was able to USB 3.0 to work with an external hard-drive, but I have tried two mice, and multiple flash drives, to no avail,

I have re-installed 16-04, also a no go.

When I shut down and have the machine show me what is going on, I get this:

```
[    8.607438] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting  [1915]]*ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[    8.607461] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [1915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[    8.611719] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    8.827757] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    9.155791] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    9.371802] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[    9.995814] usb 3.2: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[   10.515848] usb 3.2: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[   10.515910] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate usb device
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](/questions/642207/drm-errors-on-startup). Could you please check if that helps and report back? Thanks.

Comment: tried it. no help. but i was hopeful.